# Small programs running out of memory in Node on OSX?

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js, memory

I am trying to learn JavaScript, and using node to runs JS programs from the terminal like

```
node program1.js
```

I have a very simple javascript program that should create an array, but it is running out of memory with the error

```
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Program is as follows

```
function CreateArray(num) {
  array = [];
  for (i=0; i<=num; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Any reason this should be running out of memory? For an array of size 100?

Comment: You forgot to declare `i` and `array`

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
function CreateArray(num) {
  var myArray = [];
  for (var i=0; i<=num; i++) {  //var here
    myArray.push(i);
  }
  return myArray;
}
```

Comment: The array should probably be named something else as well `array` is a reserved word. Also, it should have a `var` declaration to keep it in the function scope. Bobs for the asker: you don't have to initialize arrays in JS, unless you REALLY really need it to already be filled.

Comment: @phatskat ay.. you're right. I got too focused on the loop var. Updated. thanks!